# When I use std::map to read values from a file, the value takes "," with it because the keys and values are separated by commas

Tags: c++

I have tried my best on this code but could not get desired job done.

1. Please help me to read map without "," from the file.
2. how to traverse the output to the map again.
3. If there are multiple keys the how to get the value of first key e.g key = 90, value == "hello" & key = 90, value = world. I need output of very first key.

This is what I've got so far:

```
#include <fstream>

#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::string> myMap;
    std::map<int, std::string>::iterator it;

    fstream textfile;
    textfile.open("map.txt");  // opening the file 

    if (!textfile)
    {
        cout << " Error, could not open the file. " << endl;
    }

    int key;
    string value;

    while (textfile >> key >> value)
    {
        myMap[key] = value;
    }

    // traverse to map


    it = myMap.find(90);
    if (it != myMap.end())
    {
        cout << " the value at 90 is = " << it->second << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "the value at 90 is not avaible " << endl;
    }

    it = myMap.find(9999);
    if (it != myMap.end())
    {
        cout << " the value at 9999 is = " << it->second << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "the value at 9999 is not avaible " << endl;
    }


    system("pause");
}`
```

Comment: Can you please show your file format?

Comment: "I use std::map to read values from a file" - you need to set your terminology straight.

Comment: 123,abc
25,1f2kf
4,mfkj
642,34k3
41,234j
65,erer
90,ei2
90,899efe
90,fe312
54,linb3
-3566,kuir
8909,12r3er
104,rife
420,90r3e
-610,opnfjek
56,tuen
123,james
984,5344
230,jkj34
48,r3ji
549,rj3kj
873,135
24014,feif
90948,09re
434,y2347
1,j834
0,jfkjekf
-1,love
-489,kobe
4378,bryant
-9,obj
@PriyanshGoel

Comment: @James that belongs in your *question*; not a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please help me to read map without "," from the file.

You can do that by first reading a string up to the comma using `getline` and converting it to `int`.

```
getline(textfile,key,',');//read a line upto a comma from the file
int ikey=atoi(key.c_str());//convert to int
```

> If there are multiple keys the how to get the value of first key e.g
>   key = 90, value == "hello" & key = 90, value = world. I need output of
>   very first key.

Use the `find` function to get the value of the first element with the given key.

```
myMap.find(ikey)->second
```

> how to traverse the output to the map again.

You can uses the maps iterator in a for loop to do that.

so you may do something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

....

ifstream textfile("your file name");
multimap<int,string> myMap;//key value can be duplicate here
typedef pair <int, string> IntStr_Pair;//this will be used to insert key/value pairs to the map
int ikey;
string key,value;

if(textfile)
{//file opened
    while (!textfile.eof())
    {
        getline(textfile,key,',');//read the next line upto a comma from the file, which would be the next key
        textfile>>value;//read the next value from the file

        ikey=atoi(key.c_str());//convert the key to integer

        myMap.insert(IntStr_Pair(ikey,value));//insert into map
    }
}

multimap<int,string>::iterator it;
for(it=myMap.begin();it!=myMap.end();it++)
    cout<<it->first<<"......."<<it->second<<endl;//display the key/value pair
```

To get the first value of a specific key,say 90 in your case, you could do:

```
myMap.find(90)->second
```

To get the values of all elements with the given key, you can use [`multimap::equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range) function and do something like this(this is somewhat similar to using `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` function):

```
typedef pair<multimap<int,string>::iterator,multimap<int,string>::iterator> itPair;//iterator pair

itPair range=test.equal_range(90);//get the range of all elements with the given key(90 in this case)

for( ; range.first!=range.second ; range.first++)//iterate through the range to display the elements
    cout<<range.first->first<<"....."<<range.first->second<<endl;//display key/value pairs
```

Comment: This code is working fine but it skips the values of same key. like my file contains 3 values of key 90. but its just showing me first value of key 90.

Comment: I though that is what you wanted in your question 3. "If there are multiple keys the how to get the value of first key"

Comment: well, this is the requirement of my senior who is training me in a Chinese company. Kindly let me know if there is any way I can read and print all the file with multiple values at same key. and when I need a value of specific key then output should be of very first value of the key. To be specific, my file contains 3 values of key 90, while cin & cout it should consider all but when I want value at key 90, it should give me the first value.

Comment: @James BTW if you are using `std::map` the key values are unique, so if you provide a value with a key that already existed, the previous value for that key will be replaced with the new one. If you want multiple values with the same key, you should use `std::multimap`

Comment: got you. Going to have a look on multimap function

Comment: what I have to do if I want to print all the values at key 90?? kindly let me know.

Comment: @James You can do that using `multimap::equal_range` function. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you read using `>>`, separation between the values it reads occurs only at whitespace by default. So you can't write `textfile >> key >> value` and expect to get comma separated strings in `key` & `value`. Instead, read a key value pair as a single string and then split it.

```
#include <sstream>
...
string keyValuePair, key, value;
while (textfile >> keyValuePair) {
    istringstream myStream (keyValuePair);
    getline(myStream, key, ',');
    getline(myStream, value);
    myMap[stoi(key)] = value;
}
```

Comment: Its giving me error at myStream, the error is "incomplete type is not allowed" and second error at geline is " no instance of overloaded function" although I have #include <string > included @aakashjain

Comment: @James make sure to include `<sstream>`

Answer (score 1):

> If there are multiple keys the how to get the value of first key e.g key = 90, value == "hello" & key = 90, value = world. I need output of very first key.

Keys in a map must be unique. Now you just overwrite values in the map, so it holds the last read value for each key. You should check key presence and just don't write a new value if the key is already present in the map, or you can use map of vectors:

```
while (...) {
    if (!myMap.count(key)) {
        myMap[key] = value;
    }
}
```

or

```
std::map<int, std::vector<std::string>> myMap;
...
while (...) {
    if (!myMap.count(key)) {
        myMap[key] = {};
    }
    myMap[key].push_back(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution that how to print multiple values at the same key. I used lower_bound and upper_bound function to get all the values of same key.
Here is the solution.`

```
for(auto it = myMap.lower_bound(90); it != myMap.upper_bound(90); ++it)
        cout << it->first << "->" << it->second << endl;`
```

Comment: Nice to see you found a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to consume ',' unless you don't want it in your next token.
A quickfix:

```
int key;
char comma;
string value;

while (textfile >> key >> comma >> value)
```

Comment: This will not work. Since the input format does not put spaces between commas and values, >> will read an "key,value" as a single string.

Comment: The `key` is int, so it won't be able to read past the comma, eh?